# Scala play 2 framework how can I implement a write or format on Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Scala and play 2 and haven't found a way to return a Json request from the database using Anorm. This is my simple code

```
  def locations = Action {implicit c=>
import play.api.libs.json._
 implicit val readLocations = SQL("select city,state from zips limit 1")

  Ok(Json.toJson(readLocations))
 }
```

The method is a post I simply want to return via Json 1 record from the database table there but I get this error
**Error:(57, 21) Play 2 Compiler: 
.scala:57: No Json serializer found for type anorm.SqlQuery. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
       Ok(Json.toJson(readLocations))**

Any suggestions would be welcomed, I have been switching the code above some but nothing is working. I know I need to do a Write or Format but can't seem to find out how.

```
                 ^**
```

Comment: First of all you have to run the query as mentioned in [Anorm docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm). Then you will have a type which should be serializable to json (you need a `Reads` or `Format` of that type).  By the way, reading [Play docs concerning JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to send a List of Locations. You could do:

```
  def locations = Action {implicit c=>
    import play.api.libs.json._
    implicit val locationFmt = Json.format[Location]

    case class Location(city: String, state: String)

    //Send Multiple Locations if you want
    val readLocations = SQL("select city,state from zips").list.map{case Row(city: String, state: String) =>
      Location(city, state)
    }

    // Send a single Location
    val readLocation = SQL("select city,state from zips limit 1").list.headOption.map{case Row(city: String, state: String) =>
      Location(city, state)
    }.getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException)

    Ok(Json.toJson(readLocation))
  }
```

Comment: You can read [Json Inception])https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception) to understand how `Json.format` macro works.

Comment: That code worked perfectly. I will go to the link now.